# Electric field conservation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conservative-field

I was reading on the topic **electric field** at that time i came up with a question "why electric field is conservative in nature? ". Then i searched it on google but it has been given in terms of work as well as it has been given that electric field is path independent . This has made me more confused. My question

1. Why has electric field been explained in terms of work?
2. How electric field is path independent? 
   Please refer the link below
   https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.topperlearning.com/doubts-solutions/prove-electric-field-is-conservative-in-nature-pdp2rejj&ved=2ahUKEwjoy9zLydriAhXSmeYKHd3FCS8QFjAEegQIDxAJ&usg=AOvVaw1-ozH3ynMSDkr6yFWWCoIf&cshid=1560021471540

Explain in simple way
Please don't use any mathematics here

Comment: Hi! For certain (almost all) questions in physics, there is some inherent mathematics built into the reasoning that goes into answering them because physics is a mathematical science. :)

Comment: Okkk if you want you can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The electric field is not as such necessarily defined in terms of the work done by it on a charge. What *is* inherently defined in terms of the work done by a force is whether the force is conservative or not. The question as to whether a force is conservative or not is, by definition, the question as to whether work done by the force in a closed loop is zero or not. Now, we can try to understand why we care about such a definition. This is an interesting point. If a particle moves in a closed path and the work done by the force on it is non-zero then the particle would have either gained or lost some kinetic energy by the end of the loop. Now, you can repeat the loop once more and the particle would have gained (or lost) even more kinetic energy by the end of the second loop. You get the story. What this means is that the force field either acts as a sink of energy or as a source of energy--you can dump an indefinite amount of energy into this force field, or, you can gain an indefinite amount of energy out of the force field. If the forces in nature were of this kind at a fundamental level then it would mean that we would practically not have a useful notion of the conservation of energy (this is not a very rigorous statement but that is the flavor). So, that is why we care if a force is conservative or not. If the force is conservative, after a closed loop, we would get back to the same energy we had at the beginning. But, wait! The force had done some work on the particle when the particle was yet at half the loop. But when it completes the loop, the force performs just the opposite work and gives back the particle the energy that it initially had. This suggests that, in fact, during the whole time, the force field had stored the energy that it was taking from the particle and it returns the energy it takes at the end of a loop. This suggests that the force field is indeed more physical than just a tool. And a systematic way to associate the energy that it stores is via introducing the concept of potentials. In a more mathematical manner, one can show that a force being conservative is equivalent to the existence of a potential with which the force can be associated.
2. Now, the second question is pretty simple. We just want to find out whether the electric force is of such a conservative kind. So, we did the experiment and found out that it always returns to the particle, at the end of a loop, the energy that it originally had. So, we conclude that the electric force is conservative.